# Password Encryption - MD5

Tags: php, md5

I did MD5 Password hash but since it is that `MD5 password Hash` is crackable is there any other built in password hash function in PHP?

Which is easy to implement and no need for other libraries.

Big thanks in advance

Comment: What version of PHP do you use? If you use 5.5 you can use the new [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function which handles all of this for you.

Comment: This might help you gain some insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897434/password-security-sha1-sha256-or-sha512

Comment: XAMPP 1.8.2 , PHP: 5.4.22

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.5 has new password functions built in.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

and to verify passwords you can use.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

If you are using a version of PHP earlier than 5.5 consider using the following library.

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat